# How to get cell location whose value is changed with reference to other cell value in Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-api

I have sheet in which whenever there is an edit, for example in cell "A1", the background color of this cell will be changed to green. I am using on edit trigger. This works when I manually enter value in cell "A1".

But if this cell is connected with another cell "B2" and any change in "B2" cell will automatically change value in cell "A1" but when it happens, the background color does not change. I think it is because I did not edit value manually. Is there any way that we can change background color of cell "A1" whenever it's value is changed due to another cell? Hope you got the point. I am using following script. Any help would be appreciated.

```
function HighlightCell() {

  var Sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var cell  = Sheet.getActiveCell();
 
  Logger.log(cell);
 
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  cell.setValue("Highlighted");
  
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();  
  cell.setBackground("green");
}
```

Comment: `onEdit` trigger is activated upon **user** edits only. Formulas or scripts can not trigger an `onEdit` function. I am afraid you have to redesign your logic.

Comment: Noted. Do you recommend any solution about this question?

Comment: Carlos provided a work around. Essentially you need to find a way to link the manual edit of the source cell (B1) to the target cell (A1) . If the cells are not linked between them then you can't do anything. One idea would be for your script to check all formulas of column A and adjust the cells that their formula is related to the manually edited cell. You can use `getFormulas` and then check if you edit cell B1 which of the formulas are going to be affected, and then adjust the color of these cells. Workarounds exist, the question is how open you are to these workarounds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have managed to find a solution of this by following formula concept. So if you are in sheet2 and enter value in a cell that is linked with a cell of sheet1 using formula, then it will highlight cell in sheet1. Anyone who has similar requirement, can use this function. Here is a code:

```
function FormulaGet(e) {
  
  if (e.range.getSheet().getName() == "Sheet2") {
    
  var Sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet2");
  var Notation  = Sheet.getActiveRange().getA1Notation();
  Notation = Notation.toString();  
  var cell = Sheet.getActiveCell();
  Logger.log(Notation);
  var row = cell.getRow()
  Logger.log(row);
  var col = cell.getColumn();
  Logger.log(col);
    var Sheet1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
    var formulas = Sheet1.getRange("Sheet1!B2:Q40").getFormulas();
    checkElement(formulas,Notation);
     
    }
}

function checkElement(array, str) {
  var item;
  var item1;
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    item = array[i];
    
    if (item.includes(str) === true || Array.isArray(item) && checkElement(item, str)) {
      item1=item.substring(8,10)
      Logger.log(item1);
      var Sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
      Sheet.getRange(item1).setBackground("#b7e1cd");
     
      return true;
    }
  }
  
  return false;
}
```

You can set your range as you want. I have set my range (B2:Q40) according to my need. Thank you @Carlos and @Marios for guiding me in right direction.

Answer (score 2):

The parameter in an `onEdit(e)` simple trigger, the [Event Object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#edit), will always point to the last **manually** edited cell, thus in your example, `e.range` will point to cell B2, regardless of whatever changes it made to other cells.

You can edit your trigger to check if there's an edit in a defined cell instead of A1 and point the `cell` range to the substring in the formula:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  if (e.range.getSheet().getName() == "Sheet1") {
    var formula = e.range.getFormula();
    if (formula != "") {
      HighlightCell(formula.substring(1));
    }
  }
}

function HighlightCell(cellNotation) {
  var Sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var cell  = Sheet.getRange(cellNotation); 
  cell.setValue("Highlighted");
  cell.setBackground("green");
}
```

**Sample:**

[image]

**Reference:**

[Simple Triggers: onEdit(e)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onedite)

Comment: the thing is I gave example of cell "A1", there are many cells that are edited with reference to other cells but one cell is edited at a time. So it will not always be "A1".

Comment: If you have a list of referenced cells you can plug them in to an array and loop to check if the edited cell is included. You can use my edited code.

Comment: Thank you for your help but that would not be feasible as data keeps increasing, so we can't make an array.

Comment: If there is a pattern of reference, for example, manual edits in column B will highlight corresponding cell in column A then it is possible to compute the range. But if there's none then the array is the best solution.

Comment: What if there are 100 referenced cells, do we keep on adding all the cells in an array. That would not be ideal.

Comment: In your example does B2 have a formula like =A1? or is it the reverse, A1 has formula =B2? Do you have a copy of your sheet to know what exactly the cell references are?

Comment: A1 has formula (=B2).

Comment: In that case the edited cell has no information on which cell(s) uses it as a formula. As Marios had advised you have to redesign your logic.

P.S. My script can work on the other case, B2 is =A1, in which case, getFormula() and substring is used.

Comment: @Carlos see my workaround comment if you want in the comment of the question. Maybe you want to spend some time working on that. Of course it is up to you. I upvoted anyways :)

Comment: @Carlos Just saw your function, I really think that we are near to our solution. In this script, if we give reference of the cell, it highlights that cell whose reference is given (refer to screenshot). What If we edit value in cell "A1", it should highlight cell B2. Because it has reference of A1. That is required. I really appreciate if you can advise me on this. Thank you for your previous answer.